# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError issue

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

i need your help.
i dont know why my code fails when the dimention is 10 and the dirty slots is 11 please help.

```
package Strategies;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

import Cleaning.State;

public class BFS {

private int dirty;
private Queue<State> fifo = new LinkedList<State>();
private String path = "";
private int num_of_expanded_states;
private boolean failure = false;

public BFS(State state, int dirty) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.dirty = dirty;
    this.num_of_expanded_states = 0;
    this.fifo.add(state);
}

public void startCleaning() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    successorFunction(fifo.element());
    if(failure){
        System.out.println("There is no solution under the constraint of  maximum number of dirty slots");
        return;
    }

}


public void successorFunction(State state){
    int x,y,i;

    State temp = new State(state);

//      state.printRoom();
    if(goalTest(state)){
        printPath(state);
        return;
    }


    x = state.x;
    y = state.y;


    // checking valid moves

    if(x+3 <= state.room.length-1){
        if(y+1 <= state.room.length-1){
            if(state.room[x+1][y]==1 && state.room[x+2][y]==1 && state.room[x+3][y]==1 && state.room[x+3][y+1]==1){
                for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
                    temp.room[x+i][y]=0;
                }
                temp.room[x+i-1][y+1]=0;
                temp.x = x+i-1;
                temp.y = y+1;
                temp.father = new State(state);
                temp.action = "3";
                fifo.add(temp);
            }
        }

        temp = new State(state);

        if(y-1 >= 0){
            if(state.room[x+1][y]==1 && state.room[x+2][y]==1 && state.room[x+3][y]==1 && state.room[x+3][y-1]==1){
                for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
                    temp.room[x+i][y]=0;
                }
                temp.room[x+i-1][y-1]=0;
                temp.x = x+i-1;
                temp.y = y-1;
                temp.father = new State(state);
                temp.action = "1";
                fifo.add(temp);
            }
        }
    }

    temp = new State(state);

    if(x-3 >= 0){
        if(y+1 <= state.room.length-1){
            if(state.room[x-1][y]==1 && state.room[x-2][y]==1 && state.room[x-3][y]==1 && state.room[x-3][y+1]==1){
                for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
                    temp.room[x-i][y]=0;
                }

                temp.room[x-i+1][y+1]=0;
                temp.x = x-i+1;
                temp.y = y+1;
                temp.father = new State(state);
                temp.action = "5";
                fifo.add(temp);
            }
        }

        temp = new State(state);

        if(y-1 >= 0){
            if(state.room[x-1][y]==1 && state.room[x-2][y]==1 && state.room[x-3][y]==1 && state.room[x-3][y-1]==1){
                for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
                    temp.room[x-i][y]=0;
                }

                temp.room[x-i+1][y-1]=0;
                temp.x = x-i+1;
                temp.y = y-1;
                temp.father = new State(state);
                temp.action = "7";
                fifo.add(temp);
            }
        }
    }

    temp = new State(state);

    if(y+3 <= state.room.length-1){
        if(x+1 <= state.room.length-1){
            if(state.room[x][y+1]==1 && state.room[x][y+2]==1 && state.room[x][y+3]==1 && state.room[x+1][y+3]==1){
                for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
                    temp.room[x][y+i]=0;
                }

                temp.room[x+1][y+i-1]=0;
                temp.x = x+1;
                temp.y = y+i-1;
                temp.father = new State(state);
                temp.action = "2";
                fifo.add(temp);
            }
        }

        temp = new State(state);

        if(x-1 >= 0){
            if(state.room[x][y+1]==1 && state.room[x][y+2]==1 && state.room[x][y+3]==1 && state.room[x-1][y+3]==1){
                for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
                    temp.room[x][y+i-1]=0;
                }

                temp.room[x-1][y+i-1]=0;
                temp.x = x-1;
                temp.y = y+i-1;
                temp.father = new State(state);
                temp.action = "4";
                fifo.add(temp);
            }
        }
    }

    temp = new State(state);

    if(y-3 >= 0){
        if(x+1 <= state.room.length-1){
            if(state.room[x][y-1]==1 && state.room[x][y-2]==1 && state.room[x][y-3]==1 && state.room[x+1][y-3]==1){
                for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
                    temp.room[x][y-i]=0;
                }

                temp.room[x+1][y-i+1]=0;
                temp.x = x+1;
                temp.y = y-i+1;
                temp.father = new State(state);
                temp.action = "0";
                fifo.add(temp);
            }
        }

        temp = new State(state);

        if(x-1 >= 0){
            if(state.room[x][y-1]==1 && state.room[x][y-2]==1 && state.room[x][y-3]==1 && state.room[x-1][y-3]==1){
                for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
                    temp.room[x][y-i]=0;
                }

                temp.room[x-1][y-i+1]=0;
                temp.x = x-1;
                temp.y = y-i+1;
                temp.father = new State(state);
                temp.action = "6";
                fifo.add(temp);
            }
        }
    }

    num_of_expanded_states = num_of_expanded_states+1;

    // return
    fifo.remove();
    if(fifo.isEmpty()){
        failure = true;
        return;
    }
    else{
        successorFunction(fifo.element());
    }
}

public boolean goalTest(State state){
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<state.room.length;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<state.room.length;j++){
            if(state.room[i][j] == 1){
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    if(counter <= dirty){
        return true;
    }
    else{       
        return false;
    }

}

public int pathCost(String path){

    if(path.equals(null)){
        return 0;
    }

    path.split("(?!^)");
    return path.length();
}

public void printPath(State goal_state){

    System.out.println(calculatePath(goal_state));
    System.out.println("The number of expanded nodes is: "+num_of_expanded_states);

}

public String calculatePath(State state){
    if(state.father==null){
        return path;
    }
    return calculatePath(state.father).concat(state.action);

}
}
```

and here is the code for state:

```
package Cleaning;

public class State {

public  long[][] room;
public State father;
public String action;
public int x;
public int y;


public State(State another){
    this.room = new long[another.room.length][another.room.length];
    this.father = another.father;
    this.x = another.x;
    this.y = another.y;
    this.action = another.action;

    for(int i=0; i<this.room.length; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<this.room.length; j++)
            this.room[i][j] = another.room[i][j];
}

public State() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void initializeState(int dimention){     
    int i,j;

    this.room = new long[dimention][dimention];
    this.action = "";
    this.father = new State();
    father = null;
    this.x = dimention - 1;
    this.y = 0;

    for(i=0;i<dimention;i++){
        for(j=0;j<dimention;j++){
            if(i == (dimention-1) && j==0){
                room[i][j] = 0;
            }
            else{
                room[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void printRoom(){
    for(int i=0;i<room.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<room.length;j++){
            System.out.print(room[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

i tried to do everything but i could not solve this exception please help.
and thanks for your help

the log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError at 
java.util.LinkedList.removeFirst(Unknown Source)
at java.util.LinkedList.remove(Unknown Source) at Strategies.BFS.successorFunction(BFS.java:195)
at Strategies.BFS.successorFunction(BFS.java:201)
at Strategies.BFS.successorFunction(BFS.java:201)
at Strategies.BFS.successorFunction(BFS.java:201)
at Strategies.BFS.successorFunction(BFS.java:201)
at Strategies.BFS.successorFunction(BFS.java:201)
at Strategies.BFS.successorFunction(BFS.java:201) 


there is a lot lines like the above one so i can't include all of them
```

Comment: You've posted a pretty large amount of code and not posted the location where the exception is thrown from or the trace. Not many people are going to wade through without more information and a clearer picture of where you're having your problem.

Comment: ok , sorry for that but the exception appears after at the recursive call after a lot of callings.

Comment: Also it is good practice to limit the amount of code in one method to what can fit on your screen.  You have way too much repetitive stuff in `successorFunction`

Comment: Is the recursive call that fails calculatePath?

Comment: No it does't even get there it throws exception before getting this point!

Comment: Where does it throw and exception? Please include the stacktrace in the question.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError at java.util.LinkedList.removeFirst(Unknown Source) at java.util.LinkedList.remove(Unknown Source) at Strategies.BFS.successorFunction(BFS.java:195) at Strategies.BFS.successorFunction(BFS.java:201) at Strategies.BFS.successorFunction(BFS.java:201) there is a lot lines like the above one so i can't include all of them

Comment: please edit in the last 10 or so lines of the stack trace from the exception

Comment: @user3492773 edit your question and add the stacktrace there. Your problem will either be that the Queue can never empty or that it is so large that the stack overflows. I would suspect the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your stackover-flow issue but changing successFunction from recursive to being iterative e.g.

private void successsFunction(State another) {

```
  ...
  else {
     successFunction(fifo.element());
  }
```

}

to

```
private void successFunction() {
  while(!fifo.isEmpty()) {
    another = fifo.element();
    ...
  }
}
```

This will make your problem go from stack-overflow to slow running and/or running out of memory.

I believe your real problem is that you are going through the same rooms far more times then you need to due to the way you are marking you rooms are visited combined with the way you copy the room state every time to create a new state

from you code

```
public State(State another){
    this.room = new long[another.room.length][another.room.length];
    ....

    for(int i=0; i<this.room.length; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<this.room.length; j++)
            this.room[i][j] = another.room[i][j];
}

...
private successFunction() {
  ...
  for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
     temp.room[x][y+i]=0;
  }
```

This means that you are only marking these rooms visited for this room and all the children of this room. If we had a simple house with room 1 connected to room  10 and 11 and room 10 connected to rooms 11, 100 and 101. room 11 connected to 10, 110 and 111.

- You would visit room 1, mark this as visited add rooms 10 and 11 [recuse] queue=[10,11]
- visit room 10 mark this as visited add rooms 11, 100 and 101 [recuse] queue=[11,11,100,101]
- visit room 11 mark this as visited add rooms 110 and 111 [recuse] queue=[11,100,101,,110, 111]
- visit room 11 mark this as visited add rooms 110 and 111 [recuse] queue=[11,100,101,110, 111,110,111 ]

If you print out which room you are in at that start of each successFunction, and the rooms that are on the fifo queue you will see what I mean.

I would suggest the answer to this would be to have only one collection of rooms and have each State refer to that collection.

So

```
public State(State another){
    this.room = another.room;
    ....

    //for(int i=0; i<this.room.length; i++)
    //    for(int j=0; j<this.room.length; j++)
    //        this.room[i][j] = another.room[i][j];
}
```